# Formatting output of numbers by 4 on each line

Tags: ruby

I would like to format numbers and output as groups of four so that it looks something like this:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I did:

```
def convert_to_array(str)
  arr = str.split(' ')
  new_arr = arr.sort_by(&:to_i)
  #format(new_arr.to_s)
end

def str
  string = <<-_END_
  4 6 2 14
  15 8 13 1
  10 5 9 12
  7 11 16 3
              _END_
  convert_to_array(string)
end
```

The output of this is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

I used `pp` as the `format` method:

```
require 'pp'

def format(input)
  string = input.to_s
  pp string
end
```

However the output of this looks like:

```
"[\"1\", \"2\", \"3\", \"4\", \"5\", \"6\", \"7\", \"8\", \"9\", \"10\", \"11\", \"12\
", \"13\", \"14\", \"15\", \"16\"]"
```

How can I fix the formatting as to put it into groups of four like the above example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add [Enumerable#each_slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice) to your method. Since that returns an enumerator, you then need to tack on [Enumerable#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a).

```
def convert_to_array(str)
  str.split.sort_by(&:to_i).each_slice(4).to_a
end

convert_to_array(string)
  #=> [["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  #    ["5", "6", "7", "8"],
  #    ["9", "10", "11", "12"],
  #    ["13", "14", "15", "16"]]
```

Note that [String#split](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) with no argument is the same as `split(/\s+/)`.

To display the results:

```
convert_to_array(string).each { |a| puts a.join(' ') }
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

For

```
string
  #=> "    4 6 2 14\n    15 8 13 1\n    10 5 9 12\n    7 11 16 3\n"
```

we compute

```
a = string.split
  #=> ["4", "6", "2", "14", "15", "8", "13", "1",
  #    "10", "5", "9", "12", "7", "11", "16", "3"] 
b = a.sort_by(&:to_i)
  #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
  #    "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"] 
c = b.each_slice(4)
  #=> #<Enumerator: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
  #                  "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16"]:each_slice(4)> 
c.to_a
  #=> [["1", "2", "3", "4"],
  #    ["5", "6", "7", "8"],
  #    ["9", "10", "11", "12"],
  #    ["13", "14", "15", "16"]]
```

Comment: I am most pleased when I can bring a smile to the reader's face; a lol is even better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `each_slice`

```
def put_slices(array)
  array.each_slice(4) do |slice|
    puts slice.join(' ')
  end
end

put_slices(str)
```

Comment: Oh that's awesome!

Comment: It would be even more awesome if the elements were sorted, as required by the question.